# How to encrypt as SHA256 with GPG command properly?

Tags: linux, command-line, security, encryption, gnupg

I have been using the following command for encryption:

`gpg --output encrypted.data --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 un_encrypted.data`

and decryption:

`gpg --output un_encrypted.data --decrypt encrypted.data`

I was wondering whether it's secure to do it this way, I only see 1 reference on the internet for this command, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31552829), and other websites run it without the `--cipher-algo AES256` command, which would use the default cypher, like this:

`gpg --output encrypted.data --symmetric un_encrypted.data`

Don't I need to add there a salt, isn't there a command to supply salt like with OpenSSL, or is that handled by the software automatically.

Also what happens if I run it like this, without `--symmetric`:

`gpg --output encrypted.data --cipher-algo AES256 un_encrypted.data`

My question is about running this command properly to create a secure SHA256 encrypted file. Is there any difference between the commands above?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a stable version of gpg, with `--cipher-algo AES256`, then it should encrypt using AES256 properly (SHA256 is a hash).

It picks it's own salt & key transformation rounds automatically, so you don't have to (and couldn't) pick potentially weak options yourself. OpenSSL has lots of options, but it's defaults (especially with it's `enc`) may not be the strongest. Your linked Q actually references my other answer about [OpenSSL vs GPG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28248800/3412074) - basically gpg works, it's been tested for decades, can stump big governments, and OpenSSL's `enc` command may still not have an option for an iteration count (it's 1.1.0f man page from 2017-11-02 still lists that bug).

Add some (multiple) `-v` options to see more details like the salt (772B0F3B94AD86BA below):

```
$ gpg -vvvvvvvvv  test.gpg 
gpg: using character set 'utf-8'
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
# off=0 ctb=8c tag=3 hlen=2 plen=13
:symkey enc packet: version 4, cipher 9, s2k 3, hash 2
        salt 772B0F3B94AD86BA, count 9961472 (211)
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
# off=15 ctb=d2 tag=18 hlen=2 plen=0 partial new-ctb
:encrypted data packet:
        length: unknown
        mdc_method: 2
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
# off=36 ctb=a3 tag=8 hlen=1 plen=0 indeterminate
:compressed packet: algo=1
# off=38 ctb=ad tag=11 hlen=3 plen=25420
:literal data packet:
        mode b (62), created 1519523431, name="test",
        raw data: 25405 bytes
gpg: original file name='test'
gpg: decryption okay
```

If you omit `--symmetric` then gpg will try and guess what you mean, if the file isn't gpg encrypted then it will give up/fail:

```
$ gpg -vvvvvvvvv --cipher-algo AES256 test 
gpg: using character set 'utf-8'
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: processing message failed: Unknown system error
```

Omitting the `--cipher-algo` option should use "The default  symmetric  cipher used is AES-128" (like the `man gpg` page says about that option) but defaults can vary by version or I believe overridden by your personal settings. FYI available algorithms can be listed with the `--version` option, like:

```
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

You also don't really need the `--output` option unless you like it, gpg will add & remove a `.gpg` extension as needed.

- FYI, here's a link to [RFC2440](http://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/gnupg/rfc2440-3.html) describing the data elements used by OpenPGP (at least back in 1999, though I'm sure it's almost entirely still relevant, especially descriptions of things like String-to-key (s2k) and iterations and salt)